# cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a number of packages in SSIS that moves data from an oracle data source to Sql Server.

A new package was failing and I could not figure out what was going on. It was giving the message **"cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types"**

It was weird that the package worked on my local machine but when deployed to server it always failed.

I already do a data conversion of my string values from dt_Wstr to dt_str.

All of my string columns on SQL Server are varchar

At wits end I decided to try to change the nps_lang registry value for oracle on the server box.

These are the settings that I changed.

```
(old)AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
(new)AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
```

It worked! At least so I thought.

The next day all the other packages that had been running fine are now failing.

Now my questions are what are the difference between these two that would cause one to fail and the others not?

Is there a character set that I could use that would work with both?

Any other suggestions to get all of my packages to run successfully on the server?

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with MySQL sources and SSIS packages and it ended up being a point difference in drivers (4.3.0123 versus 4.3.1022). Might be worth comparing your development environment to the servers version

Comment: Should have mentioned this but I checked that too and they are both the same oracle 12 version